# Use header case for fields

Tags: graphql

I’d like to know if it’s possible to use header casing for GraphQL field names, like that:

```
type Headers {
  Accept: String
  Content-Type: String
}
```

I have tried this way, with simple quotes, double quotes and backticks : neither of these works.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GraphQL names](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Names) can contain ASCII letters, digits, and underscores only, and can't begin with digits.  There's no way to declare or consume fields that don't match this rule.  You just can't have a field named `Content-Type`.

It seems conventional for field names to start with lowercase letters, but this isn't required.  `Accept` is a valid field name, but a more typical API would use camelCase naming

```
type Headers {
  accept: String
  contentType: String
}
```

Comment: That’s what I thought ! Thanks for the quick reply.